# What is a simple way in Ruby to show the date and time?

Tags: ruby, date, datetime

I would like something in Ruby roughly equivalent to `time.asctime()` in Python:

```python
import time
print(time.asctime())
```

outputs:

```text
Sun Sep 11 10:12:48 2022
```

I'd like to avoid having to use `strftime` and having to remember or look up the formats.  Also, ideally I'd like both day of the week (e.g., `Sun`) and the UTC timezone difference (e.g., `-0400`), but I'd settle for just day of the week.

Answer (score 4):

```ruby
puts Time.now.asctime
```

outputs:

```text
Sun Sep 11 10:24:46 2022
```

Answer (score 1):

### Simple String Output

Ruby supports lots of [Time](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Time.html), [Date](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html), and [DateTime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html) objects and output formats. While I think the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73681318/1301972) is closer to the output format you want, the following is potentially simpler and possibly sufficient for many needs when just considering standard output or standard error:

```rb
p Time.now.to_s
#=> 2022-09-11 14:10:57 -0400

# using interpolation
p "Time: #{Time.now.to_s}"
#=> "Time: 2022-09-11 14:15:51 -0400"
```

### Other Considerations

Note that if you want to use the results for any sort of comparison or calculation, you'll likely need to convert the result to one of the three object types described above. That's the main reason I mention them. Unless it's just printing to the screen, you should think about how you plan to *use* the result before deciding which of the objects will be most useful for you.

Comment: In the string interpolation, isn't the explicit call to `#to_s` extraneous?

Comment: `p Time.now.to_s` is equivalent to `puts Time.now.to_s.inspect`, and the `inspect` causes the time to be printed with surrounding double quotes, which is not what the OP wanted. I would do a `puts Time.now` instead.

Comment: @user1934428 #puts and #p are not identical. Kernal#puts always returns nil, which is rarely what you expect if you want to return a value and not just output to an IO stream. YMMV.

Comment: @Chris Maybe. Interpolation implicitly calls #inspect, which can be different from #to_s on some objects. In this case it probably doesn’t matter,  but there are cases where it does. I often find explicit coercion is clearer, and that very few people expect #inspect. YMMV.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs: Exactly. Aside from the return value (which is rarely of interest anyway), `p` applies `inspect` to it's arguments, and this is the problem here. BTW, interpolation calls `to_s`, not `inspect`. It just happens that if a class does not have its own `to_s`, that interpolation reverts to `inspect`.

Comment: Thanks @ToddA.Jacobs!  I like that your `Time.now.to_s` shows the timezone difference with UTC (`-0400`).  But it does not have the day of the week.  Ideally I'd like both timezone difference and day-of-the-week (I now updated the question with that), but I'm guessing then I'd have to use `strftime()`.